# How to Identify that app run on which monitor in UWP C#

Tags: uwp

I have two monitor. I need to write logic according to monitor? if app run on monitor 1 (primary) then I need some logic and if app run on monitor 2 (non primary) then I need to write some other logic.

How to Identify that app run on which monitor in UWP C#

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Identify that app run on which monitor in UWP C#

We could use [`Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation) to get current display info, unfortunately, `DisplayInformation` does not contain monitor device info. If you do want this feature, please feel free post this on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: The link is not available anymore.